# The combination Keyboard Avoidance, ScrollView, and multiline TextInput hides part of the ScrollView

Tags: ios, react-native

I currently have a setup that looks like this:

```
  <ScrollView> 
    ... 
    <TextInput multiline={true} />
    ...
    <NextButton />
  </ScrollView>
```

When I type into the multiline TextInput, the keyboard shows up, and begins to "Hide" parts of the ScrollView.

If I typed too much, it would even begin to hide parts of the TextInput.

I can add a KeyboardAvoidingView, but the result is still that parts of the ScrollView are hidden:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
  ...
  <ScrollView> 
    ... 
    <TextInput multiline={true} />
    ...
    <NextButton />
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvodingView>
```

In this GIF, you can see that if I scroll down, I can "glimpse" the OK button, but can't access it.

I'm not quite sure how to debug this. As a stopgap, I am detecting keyboard appearance, and adding a "spacer view" at the bottom of the ScrollView, but I would definitely prefer to avoid this.

What would the steps be to debug this further?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Yes, I think I used react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) addresses this issue reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `SafeAreaView`. The reason the button is not accessible is that the KeyboardAvoidingView takes the dimension wrong. You need to combine the two. On Android you should also set `behaviour` as otherwise it is not working.

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>
    ...
    <ScrollView> 
      ... 
      <TextInput multiline={true} />
      ...
      <NextButton />
    </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAvodingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

of course the Views are all flex=1